# Combinations and Permutations - password case

Tags: permutations, combinations

Passwords on a network are made up of two parts. One part consists of three letters of the alphabet, not necessarily different, and five digits, not necessarily different. How many passwords are possible on this network?

Comment: Welcome to math SE. People here like to see what you have tried in order to solve your problem. This is why you are attracting downvote. Next time you ask a question, please include your thoughts.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am going to assume that these passwords are not case sensitive. So there are 26 distinct letters and 10 distinct digits. I am also going to assume that the two "parts" you describe have fixed positions, e.g. the passwords are made up of 3 sequential letters followed by 5 sequential digits.

If my assumptions are true, then total number of possible passwords is $26^3 \cdot 10^5 = 1,757,600,000$.

Visually, consider each possible password character: _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _. Since characters are allowed to repeat, total number of possibilities is the product of the numbers of possibilities at each position, i.e. $26 \times 26 \times 26 \times 10 \times 10 \times 10 \times 10 \times 10$, i.e. $26^3\cdot 10^5$.

Comment: FYI, this is a fairly minor point, but you're assuming it's the English alphabet which is being used. As [How Many Letters Are There in the Alphabet?](https://wordcounter.net/blog/2015/11/24/10950_how-many-letters-alphabet.html) discusses, for example, Arabic has $28$, Russian has $33$, Spanish has $29$, Italian has $21$ and Greek has $24$. Also, [Polish alphabet](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polish_alphabet) states Polish has $32$ letters in its alphabet.

Comment: For that matter, I'm also assuming that the digits are base-10 Hindu-Arabic numerals. ;) The question was in English, and the purview of my answer was limited to combinatorics, so I think these assumptions aren't unreasonable, but feel free to swap out the 26 to get a non-English-specific answer... if there are $a$ letters and $b$ digits then the answer is $a^3 \cdot b^5$.

Comment: On a wholly separate note, I too find orthography utterly fascinating in its own right. :D Even within a single language, what is considered a "letter" is not always constant over time, as a matter of category, or sometimes even of concept. For example, at least according to the Real Academia Española, Spanish in fact now has only 27 letters, since 2010 when they stopped counting the digraphs $\mathrm{ch}$ and $\mathrm{ll}$ as distinct letters. And don't even get me started on how "alphabets" with their "letters" differ radically from abjads, abugidas, syllabaries, or logographic scripts... :D